# React Typescript: text translation file with JSX

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a file with all the text to be translated...

```
///translations.txt
const TEXT: { [x: string]: { [y: string]: string } } = { //<== is JSX a string?
  en: {
    joinNow: <React.Fragment>Join <b>Now<b/></React.Fragment>,
    signUp: <React.Fragment>Sign <b>Up<b/></React.Fragment>,
    },
};
```

Then I import it..

```
import { TEXT } from '../../translations';
const txt = TEXT[global.language]; // global.language = en

return (
   {txt.joinNow} // <== I want the word `now` to be inbold
...
```

Comment: for your particular case, you might want to take a look to this https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml
however, given it's a presentational detail you might want to use css rather than styling on your traslation text. And close your tags as `</b>`, not `<b/>`

Answer (score 0):

take a look to dangerouslysetinnerhtmlhttps://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml

This prop will allow you to render html from variables.

```
// retrieve your property to render
const joinNow = '<React.Fragment>Join <b>Now</b></React.Fragment>'

return (
  <span dangerouslySetInnerHTML={ __html: joinNow }></span>
)
```

However, given this is a presentational detail, you should consider storing your translations in plain text, and style with css from your components